# Is there a way to set symbolic links to only executable files in Linux?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

I have a directory with code files and executable files and I want to know how to create a symbolic link only to executable files in that directory?

I know that `path-of-directory/*` selects all files however I only want the executables.

Comment: The notion of executability is of course in the eye of the beholder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `find` to list executable files:

```
find /foo -type f -executable
```

You can then use the `-exec` option to create the link.

```
   -exec command ;
          Execute  command;  true  if 0 status is returned.  All following
          arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until
          an  argument  consisting of `;' is encountered.  The string `{}'
          is replaced by the current file name being processed  everywhere
          it occurs in the arguments to the command [...]
```

So, to create a link in `~/bar` to each executable file in `~/foo`, you would do

```
find ~/foo -type f -executable -exec ln -s {} ~/bar \;
```

Note that this is not searching for binary files, simply for those that have the executable bit set.

Comment: Thanks terdon I tried your method and it work like I wanted!

Comment: @tony_pt you're very welcome. If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: What  `man find` says about `-executable`:  "Because this test is based only on the result of the access(2) system call, there is no guarantee that a file for which this test succeeds can actually be executed". However this caution is probably irrelevant for Joe averages files on a local disk.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes, that's why I clarify that this will only search for files that have the executable bit set at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility:

```
for i in ~/foo/*; do [ -x "$i" ] && ln -s "$i" ~/bar; done
```

`-x` tests if the file exists and is executable. See `man test` for more information.

If you want to create working relative links you might need to think about how you provide your directory paths, or use the `-r` option to `ln` (which is a somewhat new GNU extension (≥ 8.16), but should be present in all "recent" distributions).

If you want to traverse into subdirectories using this method, activate `globstar` with `shopt -s globstar` and give the search path as `~/foo/**` (see `globstar` in the Bash manual).

The `[ -x ]` test will include directories with the executable bit set, which might not be wanted. If it is a problem, an extra `[ -f ]` test to see if the match is a file can be added.

Answer (score 1):

If you use zsh (and I recommend trying it for magic like this), you can simply use a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_2.html).

```
ln -s /path/to/foo/*(*) /path/to/bar
```

`(*)` means just executable files; you can use similar constructions for files, directories, links, etc. or even more advanced sorting and manipulation operations.